# Convert Plain Old JavaScript Object into Require.js module

Tags: javascript, requirejs

I'm refactoring a JavaScript application to use Require.js. So far so good until this conceptual struggle I'm having.

In a module, many new objects are created:

```
new Dealer(self.c, self.config, "Dealership", "2333 South Loop West, Houston, TX 77054", 6.07, "(713) 558-8100", "9am - 9pm", 0, "http://mikecalverttoyota.com/"),
new Dealer(self.c, self.config, "Dealership", "9400 Southwest Freeway, Houston, TX 77074", 8.89, "(713) 270-3900", "8:30am - 9pm", 1, "http://www.sterlingmccalltoyota.com/")
```

Right now, these are created just fine - another file, `dealer.js` has the object definition:

```
function Dealer(c, config, name, address, distance, phone, hours, index, url) {
    var self = this;
    self.c = c;
    self.config = config;
    ...
}
```

Conceptually, how do I convert the Dealer object into a require.js module so that I can require it in other modules, and then instantiate copies of it in those modules?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is the easiest way to do it:

```
define(function () {
    function Dealer(c, config, name, address, distance, phone, hours, index, url) {
        var self = this;
        self.c = c;
        self.config = config;
        ...
    }

    return Dealer;
});
```

The code above could be in a file named `dealer.js`. Then in the module where you use it:

```
define(['dealer'], function (Dealer) {

    new Dealer(self.c, self.config, "Dealership", "2333 South Loop West, Houston, TX 77054", 6.07, "(713) 558-8100", "9am - 9pm", 0, "http://mikecalverttoyota.com/"),
    new Dealer(self.c, self.config, "Dealership", "9400 Southwest Freeway, Houston, TX 77074", 8.89, "(713) 270-3900", "8:30am - 9pm", 1, "http://www.sterlingmccalltoyota.com/")
});
```

Comment: So simple and elegant. Thank you.